# Retrieve specific values from csv using Datatool and divide them by each other

Tags: datatool

So I am loading a csv file that looks something like this:

> est;dens;mwp 
> ols11;0.1;. 
> ols12;0.09;0.001

I want to use the following code to divide two numbers. I use the .csv in a table, but I also refer to them in the text, and would like this to be automated. But I get the following error from the code: `Missing number, treated as zero.` for the line `\basiceval{\x/\y}`. I am not very experienced with evaluating numbers in LaTex, so any help would be appreciated!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{;}
\DTLloaddb{mun_reg}{63_mun_result.csv}
\def\basiceval#1{\the\numexpr#1\relax}

\begin{document}
\def\x{\DTLfetch{mun_reg}{est}{ols11}{dens}}
\def\y{\DTLfetch{mun_reg}{est}{ols12}{dens}}
\basiceval{\x/\y}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with the approach in the question: first `\numexpr` performs integer division, so you can't use it for 0.1/0.09, and second the `\DTLfetch` statement is not expanded in the `\def`, so you essentially try to divide a (very complex) macro by another macro, instead of dividing two numbers as you expect.

To perform calculations on decimal numbers `datatool` has some built-in mathematical functions, among which `\DTLdiv` (for division). The input of these functions is supposed to be a macro holding a value, and the result is also stored in a macro. For storing database values in a macro you can use `\DTLgetvalueforkey` instead of `\DTLfetch`. Note that for `\DTLgetvalueforkey` the order of the column and row specification is different (first the column for which you want to find the value, then the reference column and row).

For more information on the mathematical functions you can read section 3 of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool-user.pdf), specifically page 24 and further.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{;}
\DTLloaddb{mun_reg}{63_mun_result.csv}

\begin{document}
\DTLgetvalueforkey{\myx}{dens}{mun_reg}{est}{ols11}
\DTLgetvalueforkey{\myy}{dens}{mun_reg}{est}{ols12}
\DTLdiv{\mydiv}{\myx}{\myy}
Result: \mydiv
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I suspected that there should be a division in Datatools, but I am quite new to macros and that package, so I had some issues understanding the documentation properly. This worked like a charm, and I understand more how macros work! Thank you very much!

Comment: I also wanted to specify what decimals I wanted. For anyone also reading this, I did this by adding `\DTLround{\mydiv}{\mydiv}{2}` below `\DTLdiv{\mydiv}{\myx}{\myy}`, giving 2 decimals!